# SQL Server foreign key ID and entity property

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

For school I'm working on a project in C# WPF and SQL Server. I made the database and use Linq to SQL. Now I got the following tables:

```
Patients
-------
ID                 int PK
name               varchar
insurancecompany   int FK

Insurancecompanies
-------
ID                 int PK
name               varchar
```

`insurancecompany` in `patients` is a FK to `id` in `insurancecompanies`

I left out a lot of unnecessary columns for my question since it would take too long. So I added the database tables to my Linq to SQL database model. I created an instance to the `patient` class. Looking at it, I see 2 properties. One is `insurancecompany`, which is an `int`. The other is `insurancecompany1`, which is an `insurancecompany` type.

Is it safe to make the `int` private, or remove it? Or is there a way to make it so there's only one property?

Comment: You can make it private. You won't be able to remove it because it's part of an association. If you make it private, you always must set an `Insurancecompany` object. Only setting an Id may be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that database model sees that you have a foreign key relationship to Insurancecompanies, it looks at the value you've assigned it and then finds that insurancecompany and adds it as an additional property which it calls "insurancecompany1" (it would have called it "insurancecompany" but couldn't because you already have a property with that name).

This is a nice feature because it makes it easy to look at the insurance company for a given patient without needing to use joins;

```
var dave = patient();
//assign a patient from your database to "dave" here..
 var nameOfDavesInsuranceCompany = dave.insurancecompany1.name;
```

If you remove the int insurancecompany you will loose this feature because the model would no longer be able to work out which insurance company to look at. You could make it private but you would loose the ability to assign an insurance company to patient by simply giving an int value (you would always have to set an insurancecompany object to insurancecompany1).

If you don't like the names, you could rename insurancecompany to something like insurancCompanyId and then call insurancecompany1 insuranceCompany.